# stencil start causes "Error during css compilation by the primary engine:"

Tags: bigcommerce

I've just set up the Stencil CLI on a new laptop. When I run `stencil start` I get the bellow error. It reads as if it's an issue with one of my scss files however, the exact same project runs fine on my two older computers. I haven't been able to find anything online relating to this error message or hinting at how I could begin to troubleshoot it. If anyone has any info it would be greatly appreciated.

```
Error during css compilation by the primary engine:
Error: Top-level selectors may not contain the parent selector "&".
   ╷
36 │ &::placeholder {
   │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  dh-custom/dh-global.scss 36:1  @import
  dh-custom/dh-theme.scss 8:9    @import
  stdin 94:9                     root stylesheet
Will retry with a fallback engine
```

Stencil starts and runs Browsersync, however it randomly glitches and reloads itself.

I've tried using node 10.17, 10.24, 12.13, and 12.22.7.
The computer is an Apple MacBook Pro with an m1 max chip.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1873

Could it be you have a different set of npm packages installed on this laptop, and now the error is surfacing.